# XPath query in php

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Basically I have two questions.

1) How do I extract data by first checking parent then child and then extract data from it. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="product-container product-block" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div class="left-block">
    <div class="product-image-container image">
       <div class="leo-more-info" data-idproduct="68"></div>
        <a class="product_img_link" href="http://www.pakdukaan.com/nvidia-graphics-cards/68-zotac-geforce-gtx-980-ti-amp-zt-90503-10p-.html?search_query=GTX+980&amp;results=2&amp;cate=" title="ZOTAC GeForce GTX 980 Ti AMP! (ZT-90503-10P)" itemprop="url">
            <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="http://www.pakdukaan.com/217-home_default/zotac-geforce-gtx-980-ti-amp-zt-90503-10p-.jpg" alt="ZOTAC GeForce GTX 980 Ti AMP! (ZT-90503-10P) in Pakistan" title="ZOTAC GeForce GTX 980 Ti AMP! (ZT-90503-10P) in Pakistan" itemprop="image" />
            <span class="product-additional" data-idproduct="68"></span>
```

I want to extract img's src. I know I can just use

```
(//img[@class="replace-2x img-responsive"])//@src
```

But I want first to check if it's parent is

```
<div class="product-container product-block"
```

then

```
<div class="left-block">
```

And then

```
<img class="replace-2x img-responsive"
```

Here is what I have written to get it

```
(/div[@class="left-block"]/div[@class="product-container product-block"]//img[@class="replace-2x img-responsive"])//@src
```

But it wouldn't show any result...

2)and my another question is...

If there are two similar divs for instance...

```
<div class="content_price" itemprop="offers">
<span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">79,999</span>
</div>
<div class="content_price" itemprop="offers">
<span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">79,999</span>
</div>
```

How do I skip one? I mean pick one of them

Comment: 1) `/div[@class="product-container product-block"]/div[@class="left-block"]//img[@class="replace-2x img-responsive"]/@src`

Comment: 2) `(/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price product-price"])[1]` or to take second - [2]